# Expandable rows in listview or Grid

Tags: .net, winforms

Is there any way to create an expandable grid or list view in .Net windows application?
The rows should expand down if user press a + button on the left of each main row. Is it possible to create it without paint function?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Which UI framework? WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, LightSwitch, ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC, ...?

Comment: In WinForms with vb.net or c#.net.. Sorry for confusing...

Answer (score 1):

I would [recommend you Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview). A freeware variant "Better ListView Express" is also available. It supports both expandable items and groups, which behave just like the Windows Explorer (unlike .NET ListView, groups in Better ListView can be selected, focused, contain images of any size etc.):

[image]

Comment: The ".NET ListView" supports everything that the one in Windows Explorer does. They're identical controls.

Comment: There are features, however, that are not supported by the .NET ListView (which is a wrapper for the same Win32 control, I agree with you on that) even though the underlying control does support that. For example, try to enable "Thumbnail" view (items with images, much larger than the LargeIcon view), put focus rectangle on group or focus a single sub-item. These features are simply not accessible through the .NET wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The standard ListView supports grouping

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezh1batz.aspx

```
// Adds a new group that has a left-aligned header
listView1.Groups.Add(new ListViewGroup("List item text",
HorizontalAlignment.Left));
```